# Regex Non-Greedy (Lazy)

Tags: c#, regex, html-table, non-greedy

I'm attempting to non-greedily parse out TD tags. I'm starting with something like this:

```
<TD>stuff<TD align="right">More stuff<TD align="right>Other stuff<TD>things<TD>more things
```

I'm using the below as my regex:

```
Regex.Split(tempS, @"\<TD[.\s]*?\>");
```

The records return as below:

```
""
"stuff<TD align="right">More stuff<TD align="right>Other stuff"
"things"
"more things"
```

Why is it not splitting that first full result (the one starting with "stuff")? How can I adjust the regex to split on all instances of the TD tag with or without parameters?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: `.` just means a literal dot in character class `[.]`, not 'any character. You _may_ have more success with `[^>]*`, _but_ it would break on a `>` in an attribute (which is one of the reasons why we often look at parsers rather the regexes to manipulate html & xml).

Comment: @Wrikken The HTML here is pretty static. There isn't much variation and I know the regex that would work for it. I didn't go the route of parsers because of that. Is there a way to make the . character mean 'any character' including whitespace?

Comment: I don't know the c# modifiers (in pcre it would be `/s`) to make the dot match all. However `[^>]*>` is functionally equivalent to `(.|\s)*?>`, and probably easier on the regex.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The regex you want is `<TD[^>]*>`:

```
<     # Match opening tag
TD    # Followed by TD
[^>]* # Followed by anything not a > (zero or more)
>     # Closing tag
```

Note: `.` matches anything (including whitespace) so `[.\s]*?` is redundant and wrong as `[.]` matches a literal `.` so use `.*?`.

Comment: By default, . does not match new line but \s does.

Answer (score 61):

For non greedy match, try this `<TD.*?>`

Comment: @Hambone Because `?` after the quantifier `*` tells Regex engine to stop eating symbols when it finds the first match of the expression which follows `?`, that is - `>`. The difference is because of greedy vs non-greedy `*`.

Answer (score 19):

From https://regex101.com/

- `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many
  times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, **as few times as possible**, expanding as needed (lazy)