# Ungreedy regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex, regex-greedy

I have a string like `fcsNotificationZK44_0376300009215000019_4158794.xml` and a pattern `(fcs.*)_` the target is to get `fcsNotificationZK44` but standart C# `Regex` matched at `fcsNotificationZK44_0376300009215000019` becouse it is greedy. In javascript I can use `/U` modifier to turn on ungreedy mode but how to solve it in C# `Regex`? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex Non-Greedy (Lazy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844168/regex-non-greedy-lazy)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `*?` to make the `*` non-greedy.

Reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: Then you should tag it and credit @NightOwl888 as the correct/best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a not operator:

```
(fcs[^_]*)_
```