# Extracting repeated patterns from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a program in which the user can input various values, amongst which square root values. I've tried designing a system where if the user inputs `sqrt(number)`, then the program will extract the number, then do `Math.Sqrt()` on that number, and then pass it back.

The main problem arises when the theoretical possibility of something like `Sqrt(4) / Sqrt(5)` comes along. Because then not only am I dealing with one `sqrt()` statement, but I have to deal with the second as well.

The pattern I've been using for Regex is this:

```
string Pattern = @"sqrt\((.*)\)";
```

How can I modify this pattern to allow for the possibility of multiple square roots due to fractions?

I was also told to perhaps look into creating a parser for this. Would this be an appropriate solution?

Comment: See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844168/regex-non-greedy) for the solution to your immediate problem. If you want to write a parser, then research how to do so - that would be too broad to fit in a single Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: The duplicate you've marked doesn't make sense to me. I don't understand how that answer can be applied in my context.

Comment: `.*?` instead of `.*` to make it non-greedy.

Comment: Well, actually, that lazy dot matching might not work, use balanced construct: `string Pattern = @"sqrt\(((?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*)(?(o)(?!))\)";`

Comment: Ok, can you please explain to me in detail what the heck that line of code does.